# Usage of with in some sentences

Tags: adverbs

I wonder if i can use ''with'' in sentence below:

> As the other firms , we sell with VAT of %20.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners on StackExchcange. Can you say a little more about how you want to use 'with'? What meaning are you trying to convey?

Answer (score 1):

> As the other firms, we sell with VAT of %20.

I understand this sentence but it is not completely idiomatic.

When it comes to VAT (Value Added Tax) in the UK we refer to prices as being either *inclusive* or *exclusive* of VAT.

For example:

> our prices are *inclusive* of VAT

or

> our prices *include* VAT

We would normally say "as *with* other firms". Also the percentage symbol should be placed *after* the numerals:

> As **with** other firms, our prices are *inclusive* of VAT at **20%**.

The important point to remember here is that this is not a lesson in grammar so much as it is a lesson in using *correct terminology*. To say you give something "with" something else is perfectly acceptable in some situations, but in this context saying "*with VAT*" does not make any sense to me because it doesn't make clear whether you have added the VAT on or not. In the UK some items such as books and children's clothes are not subject to VAT and are spoken of as being "exempt". When you use your own terminology like "with" it is not clear whether you mean something is subject to VAT or that your quoted price includes it. When you use the correct terminology that everybody should be familiar with it is clear and without ambiguity.

Comment: I can’t give more examples but i just want to learn if the way of use “ with” is correct grammatically.

Comment: @languagelearner No I don't believe it is. As I explained the correct terminology is "inclusive" or "exclusive". Saying something is "with" VAT does not make it clear to me if the VAT has been added on or needs to be added on.

Comment: What about this sentence : we sell with receipt . Is this wrong too. ?

Comment: @languagelearner I would say "we issue receipts", or "we give receipts".